# How do I fix "pip"?

Tags: python, selenium, pip

I have python 3.8.0 (on a Windows PC)

When I try to run: `pip install selenium` I get the following error:

```
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"c:\python38\python.exe" "C:\Python38\Scripts\pip.exe" install selenium': The system cannot find the file specified.
```

`python pip install selenium` and `py pip install selenium` both give me this error:

```
can't open file 'pip': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

`pip3 install selenium`:

```
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"c:\python38\python.exe" error: "C:\Python38\Scripts\pip3.exe" install selenium': The system cannot find the file specified.
```

When I run: `python -m pip --version` I get:

```
pip 20.0.2 from C:\Users\<UserName>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.8)
```

I'm having the same problems trying to install django as well.

Comment: Have you installed PIP? Is it in your PATH?

Comment: Seems like you are sometimes forgetting the `-m` in `python -m pip somecommand` or `py -m pip somecommand`.

Comment: 1. "python -m pip install django" worked. What is the use of "-m"?

Comment: 2. How would I make sure that PIP is in my PATH?

Comment: Don't modify `PATH`. See the following for details: https://snarky.ca/why-you-should-use-python-m-pip/

Comment: The documentation explains `-m`. Sorry can’t easily link am on mobile.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html

Comment: If I was you, I'd uninstall current Python installation and I would re-install with 'install for all users' checked during installation and all the issues would be solved, pip would work like a charm. Or you can navigate to the Python installation folders `Scripts` folder and open a command prompt there and try running pip that way.

Comment: You should be running CMD as admin when you're doing 'pip install'  on Windows.

Answer (score 25):

Try below command and it works for me:

```
python -m pip install -U --force pip
```

Above command will first uninstall pip from yours system if already installed and install a fresh version. Once done just type pip and press enter. You will see pip common commands and general options.

Now try to install any module as per your choice.
For Example:

```
pip install sklearn
```

If installation begin means your issue has been resolved.

Answer (score 17):

Your output: `C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pip` , makes me think that you've messed-up your pip installation.

To recover do the following:

- Run CMD as admin
- Do a `python -m pip install -U --force pip` (this will fix your pip installation)
- Then close the CMD and open another admin CMD to make sure you get the PATH updates effectively
- Do `pip install -U --force selenium`

This should help to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and found the solution:

1. First check whether pip installed or not , in command prompt try `pip --version`, you should get something like this - `pip 22.0.4`.
2. if not installed (command not recognized) try to use install pip-
   using curl, try this command -
   `curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py`
3. then check again with `pip --version`

This [website](https://www.activestate.com/resources/quick-reads/how-to-install-pip-on-windows/) has detailed steps.

Answer (score 0):

Do in your terminal (fix your pip installation) ️
python -m pip install -U --force pip
Then Do
pip install -U --force selenium

Comment: This is a duplicate of the [answer with the most upvotes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61285288/18145256).