# I reinstalled python because I was having issues with pip and now pip wont work at all

Tags: python, pip, path, pyinstaller

Everytime I try to run anything in pip from my command window I get this

`C:\WINDOWS\system32>pip --version Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"c:\python39\python.exe"  "C:\Python39\Scripts\pip.exe" --version': The system cannot find the file specified.`

This is my path for my user

[image]

And this is my path for my system variables

[image]

This all started because I was trying to install pyinstaller for a project but no matter what I did it wouldn't recognise the module existed despite pip saying it had been installed.

The file defo exists:

[image]

Does anyone know a solution for this?

Comment: Are you sure you re-installed Python correctly? Have you checked to see if `C:\Python39\Scripts\pip.exe` exists? Just having the location to a probable Python interpreter in your path doesn't mean that the file is actually there!

Comment: pip.exe definitely exists in scripts

Comment: Try this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/64230868/5347875. Just the `pip` part, not the `sklearn` thing.

Comment: that didn't fix it sadly

Comment: Is this program there? `c:\python39\python.exe`.

Comment: Also, can you run `python -m pip` without issue?

Comment: it wasn't there so I put an answer below - but it turns out that it installed python to a place that isn't in my system variables path - basically I think it installed it at a user level rather than a system level - it's a little over my head as I don't properly understand path.

Comment: No worries, path stuff can get tricky. Glad you figured it out!

Comment: thanks for your help, it ach helped me figure out what was wrong!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so - a really weird fix to this issue, it turns out when I reinstalled python it didn't even install python.exe to the C:\Python39 file.

Instead it installed it to

C:\Users\aaron\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39 which is not in my system variables path.

I literally copied and pasted the files across... and it worked? so yeah if someone has this problem in future try that.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error when I ran `python -m pip install --user pipx.` I just reinstalled Python.

```
WARNING: You are using pip version 20.2.3; however, version 23.2.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'C:\Python39\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

I copied and ran this `C:\Python39\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip`, and it worked.